# Python - from file to data structure?

Tags: python, string

I have large file comprising ~100,000 lines. Each line corresponds to a cluster and each entry within each line is a reference i.d. for another file (protein structure in this case), e.g.

```
1hgn 1dju 3nmj 8kfn
9opu 7gfb 
4bui
```

I need to read in the file as a list of lists where each line is a sublist, thus preserving the integrity of the cluster, e.g.

```
nested_list = [['1hgn', '1dju', '3nmj', '8kfn'], ['9opu', '7gfb'], ['4bui']]
```

My current code creates a nested list but the entries within each list are a single string and not comma separated. Therefore, I cannot splice the list with indices so easily.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
S :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Super simple:

```
with open('myfile', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.split() for line in f]
```

Comment: Nope - that will do exactly what the OP asked. Yay Python & batteries included.

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to investigate the [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

```
>>> '1hgn 1dju 3nmj 8kfn'.split()
['1hgn', '1dju', '3nmj', '8kfn']
```